# Move Object Using Raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I am trying to move the y position of a UI element in it's local space by clicking and dragging with the SteamVR controller and a raycast. I am getting what appear to me to be unpredictable results.

I am trying to get the position of the raycast at the start of the drag and move it the distance between where it is and where it was started while dragging.

Here is my code:

```
if (hit.transform.name == "Content" && scrollSet == false)
{
    content = hit.transform;
    scrollSet = true;
    scrollPos = hit.transform.position ;
}

if (scrollSet == true)
{
    if (rController.triggerPressed)
    {
        y = hit.transform.position.y - scrollPos.y;
        content.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(content.transform.localPosition.x,  content.localPosition.y + y, content.transform.localPosition.z);
    }
    else
    {
        scrollSet = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the .MovePosition to .MoveTowards. But it still jumped around. It turns out that the code was only executing during the frame in which you right-clicked, so move it out of the if statement.

Here's the entire script placed into the main camera. You always need to have a target selected, so to prevent errors you need to put a gameObject with a rigidbody into "bTarg".

```
public class ClickTarget : MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject target; private Vector3 destination; private float distance; private Vector3 tTrans;

public GUIText targetDisplay; public float speed; public GameObject bTarg;

void Start () { targetDisplay.text = ""; distance = 0.0f; target = bTarg; }

void Update () { if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){ Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); RaycastHit hit; if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){ if(hit.collider != null){ if(hit.collider.tag == "Unit"){ target = hit.collider.gameObject; targetDisplay.text = "Unit: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name; destination = target.transform.position; target.rigidbody.freezeRotation = false; } if(hit.collider.tag == "Building"){ target = hit.collider.gameObject; targetDisplay.text = "Building: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name; } } } } }

void FixedUpdate(){ if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire2") && target.tag == "Unit" && GUIUtility.hotControl == 0) { Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); RaycastHit hit; if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit)){ destination = hit.point; } }

 tTrans = target.transform.position;
 distance = Vector3.Distance (tTrans, destination);
 if(target.tag == "Unit"){
     if (distance > .2f) {
         target.transform.LookAt (destination);
         target.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (target.transform.position, destination, speed);
         target.rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
     }
 }
} }
```

Comment: I am trying to do it with a raycast coming from a game object, not the mouse. Specifically the SteamVR controller. I want to hold down the trigger and drag the object in it's local space on it's y axis.

Comment: Hi OT2O, Let me install StreamVR and get back

Comment: Did you have any luck?